# d3.js Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d3.forceSimulation is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I am new to d3.js and I am trying to learn by changing/looking at chunks of code.

I am running into the following issue: I get a `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: d3.forceSimulation is not a function`

This is the line where I am getting the error:

```
const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    // .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(5))
    .force('x', d3.forceX().x(function(d) {
        return xCenter[d.category]
    }))
    .force('y', d3.forceY().y(0))
    .force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius(d => 1.1*d.r*Math.sqrt(2)))
  //.force('collision', collide)
    .on('tick', ticked)
```

I have the following d3.js version loading in my `html`: `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>`

If I load `<script src="./../d3.v6.js"></script>` nothing will render. What might be the problem here?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should also include d3-force in your scripts.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3-force@3"></script>
```